# Ansible: How can I update the system CentOS with Ansible

Tags: centos, ansible, yum

I am trying to update the CentOS systems with ansible. Unfortunately I am not able to do that.

I already tried:

```
- name: install updates
  yum: update_cache=yes
  when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat
```

Isn't working.

---

```
- name: install updates
  yum: name=* state=latest
  when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat
```

The last task works but is it true, that the task updates the system?

Answer (score 64):

The first task you're telling the system to only update the yum cache.

On the second you are effectively upgrading all packages to the latest version by using `state=latest` but you should also use `update_cache=yes` on the same task to be sure you're refreshing the cache with its latest package information.

The [yum module](http://docs.ansible.com/yum_module.html) documentation provides exactly this example:

```
- name: upgrade all packages
  yum: name=* state=latest
```

After the execution of the task, the terminal should display a message in yellow meaning the status of the task is `changed`.

Comment: How do I just install security updates and do not update all packaes?

Comment: Unfortunately this way you have extremely bad troubleshooting feedback in case something goes wrong (basically whole yum log, together with error on 1 line). Also, you can't really watch the progress of upgrade, nor get any progress log. I wish there was some special module for this.

Comment: In 2.8 Ansible it can also be defined as `yum: name: "*" state: latest` see [apt_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html).

Comment: If you will check this task via ansible-lint you'll get `[403] Package installs should not use latest`. So, I  can assume there should be a better way.